# How many ways are there to name your variables?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Button: btnDoSomething

Button: DoSomethingButton

Property: FirstName

field: _list

The first I used to much. I want to see or learn new ways for my future codes. Use the best practices or general rules for naming them.

All your variables, fields, properties, classes.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Comment: This is a survey type question with no real answer.

Comment: @Eric J. all right, thanks eric, I'm still learning about this site. Some things I didn't know.. I'll keep it in mind

Comment: what makes you think it's obsolete? and besides, it's just a style issue, as long as it designates things in a way that you understand, then in your own code just be consistent.  if it's in a project that you are working on with others, follow the naming convention of the project. when it comes to individual style preferences for naming conventions like this, you can at best come up with some general rules, but even most of the rules have exceptions, and there hasn't (as far as I am aware) been some revolution in style that makes the things you mention obsolete.

Comment: @Eric yes, agreed. oscar; no problem and it's nice to see you're willing to learn.  you can always delete your question if you agree that it doesn't meet the requirements of the site. (see: http://stackoverflow.com/faq for details about what kind of questions are intended to be asked.)

Comment: @Eric: You should be given a badge for being so effective, Also you are the first person I ever seen in this site that didn't downvote anybody! Certainly you should be given a badge for that too.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly Well, I didn't mean to express that. I mean I'd like to know the best practices or general rules, because sometimes I have a difficulty to naming these variables. Let me change it..

Comment: I do understand what you're saying, but as @Chris Farmer states, this isn't really a problem to be solved it's an open-ended style question. There are unfortunately lots of different things people consider "Best Practices" and some people will disagree vehemently with others. The idea is that you name variables in a way that gives you the information you need while you're using them. Even a simple rule like "don't use 1 letter variable names".. what about a for loop? It's not that this isn't a valid question, just not a good question for SO. Not that that will stop people from answering. :)

Comment: what you will end up seeing is a lot of people that have what they consider the "best" style, they'll tell you as if it's a fact that something is obsolete, even when there's disagreement in the community, they'll be incredulous when you disagree... the way I see it, style is to make the code readable, and to reduce as much as possible common errors caused with a truly confusing style. and with naming conventions, beyond "name things so that they make sense in context", almost everything can be justified.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly: "All modern Integrated development environments display variable types on demand, and automatically flag operations which use incompatible types, making the notation largely obsolete." this is why hungarian notation is obslete in c#. got it?

Comment: there is only one place that I actually use Hungarian anymore, and that's on controls. when looking at a page of code, it's not like the IDE pops up the variable type as my eye scans across the page. it's a useful cue for determining that it is a control, and what type it is. you don't like it, fine. but I am not the only one who feels that it's useful for controls and your incredulity because I do not subscribe to your rules is a classic arrogance that one's chosen style is "The One True Style". it's an aesthetic preference and akin to not liking the same art than a technical disagreement.

Comment: no matter how much you think of your own choice in style, you are, fortunately, not the Style Dictator, and the attitude in your message to me makes you look like a bully, which makes me even less inclined to bother listening to what you have to say. Got it?

Answer (score 3):

Too many.

Worrying about that can be a drag on your productivity. Luckily enough, other people have already done the worrying for you, so you can follow these guidelines and concentrate on other issues.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Answer (score 2):

.Net (and, I believe, MSVS) ship with a tool called "FxCop".  Which, among other things, warns you if you violate "CamelCase" conventions:

http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/tutorial.html

Two links that might help:

- [MS Style Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)
- [A Brief History of Dueling Style Guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)

Enjoy :)

PS:
Personally, I think Kernighan and Ritchie got it right in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first way of naming the button `btnDoSomething` is called [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) and its obslete now. The second way is also having the Button as a suffix which is also equally unnecessary.

Why not just use `ID="DoSomething"`?

Here is a good read: http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Comment: @Dwonvoter: why? care to explain?